# How to do functions in separate razor file in .net core?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-5.0

In .net I could palce razor helpers in a separate fie under App_Code and then use them in my razor views.

How to do it in .net core?

I know that there are no helpers, just razor functions but how to place them in a separate file and reuse in views?

Should I use a razor component or external razor library for this?
Like described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/class-libraries?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio ?

I just don't see a point of creating a whole separate project or class library for a few simple functions. But need to reuse them in various views.

Comment: Why you are not using Partial Views! Or even View Components!!??
The razor component is for Blazor.

Comment: I do use partial views... But partial views also use the same razor functions

Comment: Did you check out the View Components??? There are more sophisticated then the  Partial Views

Comment: I'm not sure if I misunderstood your requirement, I post a sample below using DI. Pls kindly let me know if it's not what you want.

Comment: Yes, you misunderstood @TinyWang, I did not ask about DI, I asked about razor functions...

Comment: I have the same need, a `@functions` or `@helper` that I can reuse from multiple razor pages. Did you figure it out?